# EditText parse to int HELP

Tags: android

First, hi to all of you. :)

I am learning Android and I am making some basic math program(game). It gets two random numbers, random operator, and 30 secs to solve math problems as much as you can.

I get error when I try to get text from EditText(Numbers only) and parse it to int. I need it because I need to compare real result to user input result.

I compile it, but when i run it on emulator, i got this error on ddms.

http://www4.slikomat.com/11/0921/bg9-Captur.jpg

Code: http://pastebin.com/u1MnZP34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized your EditText et1, hence you see NullPointer Exception. You should have something like
    et1 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.youtextid);

Comment: But you have a better explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your EditText but you never set it to anything, thus it is null.

```
EditText et1;
```

You need to add a findViewById() call for your EditText inside your onCreate, like you've done for your TextViews. Something like this is what you need I think.

```
et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

You should also really really use descriptive names for your variables. Using names like textView1, textView2, editText1 etc... is going to make your code A LOT harder to debug. Consider naming them something to do with what they are used for

firstOperandTxt, secondOperandTxt, answerEdt etc..